# Bash insert multiple lines into a text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, x-dwm

I have a list of parameters:

```
dwm.normfgcolor:
dwm.normbgcolor:
dwm.normbordercolor:
dwm.selfgcolor:
dwm.selbgcolor:
dwm.selbordercolor:
```

and a list of hex values:

```
#e6e4e3
#352231
#a19f9e
#e6e4e3
#FEE798
#e6e4e3
```

What i want to do is 'merge' them in a way that the first line in the first string corresponds to the first line in the second string and so forth. It should look like that

```
dwm.normfgcolor: #e6e4e3
dwm.normbgcolor: #352231
```

I thought of using

```
cat > output.txt<< EOF
dwm.normfgcolor: $variables?
dwm.normbgcolor:
dwm.normbordercolor:
dwm.selfgcolor:
dwm.selbgcolor:
dwm.selbordercolor:
EOF
```

with variables but I have no idea how.

Comment: Just use: `paste -d " " file1 file2`

Comment: I don't have the data in files and would prefer not to create any. The hex values are subtracted from a file using sed. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: @Vinchy. even command the paste should work. `paste -d " " <(command1) <(command2)`

Answer (score 1):

Using paste

```
paste -d " " file1 file2 
paste -d " " <(command to get input1) <(command to get input2)
paste -d " " file1 <(command to get output2)
```

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' <(command1) <(command2)
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file1 <(command2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer - used paste -d with process substitution.